# Index variable from a regression output

Tags: r, indexing, regression

After I obtain outputs from a regression, is there any way that I can index certain variable in this regression model?

E.g. regression

```
 myModel <- lm(y ~ a*b+c)
 myModelSumm <- summary(myModel)
 varNeeded <- myModelSumm$...
 print(varNeeded) = c
```

How can I index variable c in the outputs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to index a variable from the coefficients output of `summary` function you can use simple row-column indexing. Let say I am interested in the education variable from the Prestige dataset available in the car package. More specifically, you want to index out the education variable:

```
data("Prestige", package="car") #load the Prestige dataset from the car package
modelPrestige <- lm(prestige~education*income+type, data=Prestige) #run the regression
summary(modelPrestige)$coefficients["education",] #index education from the coefficients´ table
#    Estimate   Std. Error      t value     Pr(>|t|) 
#5.104321e+00 7.766489e-01 6.572237e+00 2.933852e-09
```

And further you can extract the Estime for instace:

```
summary(modelPrestige)$coefficients["education",]["Estimate"]
#Estimate 
#5.104321
```

If your interest, for whatever reason, is a TRUE|FALSE vector you can use:

```
rownames(summary(modelPrestige)$coefficients) == "education"
#[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Hope this helps!